# What is wrong with this Python list code?

Tags: python, list

I have a question about this code:

```
menu = ""
student = []
print ("What would you like to do?")
print ("\t[1] Show full gradebook")
print ("\t[2] Add Student")
print ("\t[3] Remove Student")
print ("\t[4] Modify Student Information")
print ("\t[5] Display Highest Grade")
print ("\t[6] Display Lowest Grade")
print ("\t[7] Quit")

# loop until the user decides to quit
while menu != 7:
    menu = int(input("Enter selection [1-7]"))
    if menu == 1:
        print("Name\tGrade")
        # loop through all students
        for s in student:
            print(s[0]+"\t"+str(s[1]))    
    elif menu == 2:
        # prompt user for student name
        sname = input("Student Name?") 
        # prompt user for student grade
        sgrade = int(input("Student Grade?"))
        # append student information to list
        student.append([sname, sgrade])    
    elif menu == 3:
        sname = input("Student to remove?")
        try:
            student.remove([sname, sgrade])
        except:
            if sname not in student:
                print("Not in table.")
    elif menu == 4:
        sname = input("Student to modify?")
        for s in student:
            print(s[0]+"\t"+str(s[1]))
        try:
            student.remove([sname, sgrade])
            sname = input("Name: (press Enter to keep original value)")
            sgrade = int(input("Grade: (press Enter to keep original value)"))
            student.append([sname, sgrade])
        except:
            if sname not in student:
                print("Not in table.")
    elif menu == 5:
        try:
            print(sname + " had the highest score in the class: " + str(sgrade))
        except:
            pass
    elif menu == 6:
        try:
            print(sname + " had the lowest score in the class: " + str(sgrade))
        except:
            pass
    elif menu >= 8:
        print("Invalid selection.")

print ("Terminating program... Goodbye!")
```

Every time I try options three through six with multiple students, it will do it for the student at the bottom of the list. Also, I want to know how to keep the original name or grade for a certain student when I am modifying student information.

Comment: "do it" - do what?

Comment: If you move each action to separate functions, you will see the problem. And also move the while loop to a main function. You are reusing `sgrade` variable from the previous iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not retrieving the student details from the list before each operation. Instead the previous value of `sgrade` is being used, and `sgrade` will always be the value used for the last student in the list. Therefore options 3-6 will only work for the last student.

You can fix it by using only the student name when searching the list. For example, to remove a student (option 3) you can use a list comprehension:

```
student = [s for s in student if s[0] != sname]
```

in your code:

```
elif menu == 3:
    sname = input("Student to remove?")
    len_orig = len(student)
    student = [s for s in student if s[0] != sname]
    if len_orig == len(student):
        # length unchanged therefore student not in list
        print("Not in table.")
```

Option 4 is a variation on the above. To find the student with the highest grade you can use the `max()` function:

```
highest = max(student, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Similarly the lowest can be found with `min()`:

```
lowest = min(student, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

---

In terms of data structures, a dictionary is a *far* better choice than the list. Use the student name for the key, and the grade as the value. Then operations such as adding, removing or modifying a student are trivial:

```
students = {}    # initialise

# add a student
sname = input("Student Name?") 
sgrade = int(input("Student Grade?"))
students[sname] = sgrade

# remove student
sname = input("Student to remove?")
if sname in students:
    del students[sname]
else:
    print("Not in table.")
```

etc.

Comment: I am not supposed to use a dictionary.

Comment: Anything for Options 4-6? They are different after all.

Comment: OK that's unfortunate. Then you will need to search the student list to perform the operations. I've shown an example of using a list comprehension to remove items from the list.

Comment: Re options 4-6 you can adapt the code shown for option 3. I've updated my answer with a few more hints.

Comment: The code for option 5 is supposed to have this: print(sname + " had the highest score in the class: " + str(sgrade))

Comment: The code for option 6 is supposed to have this: print(sname + " had the lowest score in the class: " + str(sgrade))

Comment: Can I see the variation for Option 4?

Comment: Also, I want my code to keep the original name or grade if I press Enter without typing what to change it to.

Comment: You can disregard my comments on Options 5-6. I figured them out. Thanks.